# Which rare drops can drop already enchanted?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a zombie spawner set up to farm exp, and I also have a skeleton spawner set up to do the same.

Because I'm using them as exp farms (getting them down to half a heart and then punching them to death), I also occasionally get rare drops from them both.

Around about a quarter of the bows that drop come with a Power I enchant, and I've gotten two enchanted golden swords from Zombie Pigmen (regular kills), but I've never had an enchantment on any of the hundreds of swords/shovels/helmets that the Zombies have dropped.

Which items have a chance of being enchanted upon their drop?

Comment: This is going to require some *SCIENCE!*...

Comment: @fredley: You mean it's not already in the wiki?

Comment: @MBraedley The wiki is contradictory. At one point it says that all weapons can have enchantments, and another it says only bows and golden swords can. That's why I want an answer.

Comment: @MrSmooth: That sounds like you're confusing drops w/enchantments vs. items that you can enchant yourself.  I don't have first hand experience, but I remember from somewhere that only pigmen and skeletons could drop enchanted items.

Comment: @MBraedley http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Drops#Rare_drops "and a 20% chance of being enchanted rare drops in general for **all** weapons a mob may drop"

Comment: @MrSmooth I've addressed your actual question in my answer, but regarding the contradiction, I assume that Zombies don't drop enchanted weapons, since if they did people would be all over themselves to update the wiki. [I've edited the information on rare drops](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/index.php?title=Drops&diff=304877&oldid=304874) to more accurately describe the observations from the code and experience, removing the contradiction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only items that can be enchanted are **Golden Swords** from Zombie Pigmen and **Bows** from Skeletons.

The swords, if enchanted, have their enchantment chosen randomly as if it were a level 5 enchantment from an enchanting table. The following enchantments are therefore possible:

Sharpness I–III
Smite I–IV
Bane of Arthropods I–IV
Knockback I–II
Fire Aspect I–II
Looting I–II

Bows, if enchanted, will always have Power I.

Comment: Any source other than the wiki?

Comment: @MrSmooth No, I won't have a chance to test for myself until the weekend unfortunately.

Comment: The bit about bows is definitely correct. Don't have any experience with the golden swords.

Comment: @SaintWacko I know the enchantments are correct, I was more worried about whether they're the only items that can be enchanted, which Kevin Reid's answer seems to indicate that they are.

Comment: @MrSmooth Ah, okay

Comment: @MrSmooth After examining the decompiled source code, I can confirm this answer is correct. The relevant function is EntityLiving.func_48085_j_ and its overrides.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for being concerned about sources! I was involved in writing [the wiki page on rare drops](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Drops#Rare_drops), which we did based on [this decompiled source code](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Talk:Drops#Rare_drop_code). I cannot vouch for that code being the actual code in Minecraft (especially as it may change in the future), but what it indicates is this:

First, *whether the drops are enchanted* is chosen, with 20% chance modified by Looting.

Then, the item to drop is chosen *depending on the above choice*. That is: If a Zombie Pigman passes the chance to get rare drops, and the chance to get enchanted rare drops, then the item will *always* be a golden sword. If the item is *not* to be enchanted, then you get an equal chance of all three possible drops.

I don't have the code for zombies, so I can't say exactly what their drops are set up to be, but no one has ever reported enchanted armor, so I assume it does not happen. Skeletons of course only drop (possibly enchanted) bows.

Comment: I'm sure the code has changed in the last 3 years but last night I had a zombie drop an enchanted golden chest plate w/Protection II. I was somewhat floored on this.